# Is there any way to check whether dependencies are installed at remote?

Tags: python, python-3.x, remote-access

I want to run a python3 script `script.py` on a remote machine that has following python modules as dependencies:

```
    1. requests
    2. paramiko
    3. scp
```

So is there any way we could check whether these requirements are fulfilled by the remote machine along with python3 installed in order to execute script.py only if requirements fulfilled.

Comment: Most simple way: run the code, it will tell you if a dependency is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As answered above you can simply run the script and if it's missing any modules it'll give you an error similar to `No module named xxx`. then you can use pip to install that module.
another way is to put the names of all the modules/dependencies in a text file usually named `requirement.txt` do a `pip install -r requirement.txt` it will install the modules if missing.

Comment: Agreed. This issue should not be overthinked imho.